# In AWS WAF, how do we define a match rule using the MD5 text transformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

AWS WAF Rules support an [MD5 text transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_TextTransformation.html), which I would like to use in a match rule. From the docs:

> MD5 - Calculate an MD5 hash from the data in the input. The computed hash is in a raw binary form.

How do we specify the “raw binary form” when defining a rule? [Elsewhere the docs suggest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_ByteMatchStatement.html) that the value should be

> Type: Base64-encoded binary data object

but it isn’t clear how to provide such a value.

[image: AWS WAF Rule Statement Editor]

I have tried supplying

- the hex digest of the MD5 hash

  ```
  $ echo -n matchme | md5sum | tr -d -- -
  033b259828f63db6a402bc162c803ef0
  ```
- the base64 encoding of the binary MD5 hash, with and without the padding

  ```
  $ echo -n matchme | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64
  AzslmCj2PbakArwWLIA+8A==
  ```
- the literal text to match (thinking that perhaps the save operation hashes the supplied value for you)

None of these values cause the match rule to hit. I have verified that setting the Text transformation to `NONE` and providing the original String to match does cause the rule to match incoming requests, for example using curl:

```
curl -H 'header-name: matchme' http://my-load-balancer.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

What value do we supply for String to match to use the MD5 text transformation successfully?

Answer (score 1):

### CloudFormation

`ByteMatchStatement` definitions [accept a `SearchStringBase64` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-bytematchstatement.html). We can compute an appropriate value at the command line:

```
$ echo -n matchme | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64
AzslmCj2PbakArwWLIA+8A==
```

and use this value to populate the template:

```yaml
- Name: "temp-md5-test"
  Priority: 1000
  Statement:
    ByteMatchStatement:
      FieldToMatch:
        SingleHeader:
          Name: "header-name"
      PositionalConstraint: "EXACTLY"
      TextTransformations:
        -
          Type: "MD5"
          Priority: 0
      SearchStringBase64: "AzslmCj2PbakArwWLIA+8A=="
```

### Python

It is possible to specify a correct value using the Python SDK by supplying the binary digest directly as the `SearchString` value to the `ByteMatchStatement`:

```py
{
    ...
    'Rules': [{
        'Name': 'md5-test',
        'Priority': 1,
        'Statement': {
            'ByteMatchStatement': {
                'SearchString': hashlib.md5(b'matchme').digest(),
                'FieldToMatch': {...},
                'TextTransformations': [
                    {
                        'Priority': 0,
                        'Type': 'MD5'
                    }
                ],
                'PositionalConstraint': 'EXACTLY'
            }
        }
    }]
    ...
}
```

For an existing WebACL, you can update an existing `ByteMatchStatement` with the correct value using

```py
import hashlib
import boto3

waf = boto3.client('wafv2')

# get the existing ACL with its rules
config = waf.get_web_acl(
    Scope='REGIONAL', 
    Name='my-web-acl', 
    Id='11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555'
)

# compute the MD5
searchstring = hashlib.md5(b'matchme').digest()

# update the Rule
config['WebACL']['Rules'][0]['Statement']['ByteMatchStatement']['SearchString'] = \
    searchstring

# save
waf.update_web_acl(
    Scope='REGIONAL', 
    Name='my-web-acl', 
    Id='11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555', 
    LockToken=config['LockToken'], 
    Rules=config['WebACL']['Rules'], 
    DefaultAction=config['WebACL']['DefaultAction'], 
    VisibilityConfig=config['WebACL']['VisibilityConfig']
)
```

---

One caution with both the CloudFormation and Python methods for defining an MD5 match rule: editing such a rule in the AWS web console will jostle the character encoding and cause the rule to stop functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible to save the matching statement as searchStringbase64 in the portal. See Object here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-rulegroup-bytematchstatement.html#cfn-wafv2-rulegroup-bytematchstatement-searchstringbase64

The trick for us was to use CDK.

```
const hash = crypto.createHash("md5").update("mysecret").digest("base64");
...
textTransformations: [{
  priority: 0,
  type: "MD5",
},],
searchStringBase64: hash,
```

If you look in the portal after pushing this the value will be in a strange encoding, (the binary format no doubt with a bunch of unknown characters showing in the browser).
This is probably why its not possible to save in the AWS portal